# difference between node n and new node

Tags: c++

If I declare a struct node in C++,after which I declare:

```
n = new node;
```

or

```
node n;
```

Are both these notations representing the same thing?

Comment: One is a pointer (I guess) to a node allocated on the heap, the other is a node on the stack (presumably).

Comment: Are the types of n the same in these two cases?

Comment: The difference between these two is similar to the difference between political parties: they seem to do radically different things, however, in fact, they just use up all your resources.

Answer (score 3):

No.

```
n = new Node;
```

is a pointer, the correct code is

```
Node* n = new Node;
```

or, with [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) (the latest C++ standard published in 2011, ant not yet implemented by several compilers, even if latest GCC 4.7 or soon to be released 4.8 is quite near)

```
auto n = new Node;
```

Actually, using raw pointers like above is frowned upon. You should consider using [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer#C.2B.2B_smart_pointers) e.g.

```
std::shared_ptr<Node> n = new Node;
```

The pointed-to node will be destroyed by later calling (perhaps indirectly)

```
delete n;
```

<sup>(notice that smart pointers do that "magically" for you)</sup>

But

```
Node n;
```

declare a variable of type `Node`. That `Node` data is destroyed at the end of current scope (i.e. at the closing `}` containing brace).

Read also about [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII).

Answer (score 2):

1. `node* n = new node;` is allocated on heap
2. `node n;` is allocated on stack

**In case 1.** when you allocate on heap using the `new` keyword you must use `node*` because you're saving a pointer to the object not the object itself. Using heap allocation is especially useful when you are going to want to use the object outside the current scope, although you have to always remember to call `delete n;` on every object allocated with the `new` keyword (unless you're using `std::shared_ptr` or anything along those lines).

```
node* make_node()
{
    node* n = new node;
    n->do_something();
    return n;
} // node n does not go out of scope here, but you'll have to call delete on it when you're done
```

**In case 2.** the object is being allocated on stack, while you don't have to call `delete` here, this one is going to go out of scope at the end of the current block:

```
void function()
{
    node n;
    n.do_something();
} // node n goes out of scope here.
```

---

Additional information about [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and other `<memory>` [goodies](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

Comment: "you must use `node*`"... or [a smart pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/106614/78845), such as `std::auto_ptr<node>`...

Answer (score 1):

Although they represent the same thing, `n` in the second case is created on the stack, where as the `n` in `n = new node;` is created on the heap storage, which must be manually `delete`d.

Also, the `n` in `n = new node` must be a pointer, created like this: `node* n;`